# Cannot compile x86 in GCC crunchbang

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, 32bit-64bit

I cannot seem to use GCC to compile C as x86. I am using crunchbang.

Simple C test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Test x86");
}
```

When compiled with:
`gcc -o 64 test.c`
I get no errors or output whatsoever.
However, when compiled with:
`gcc -o 64 -m32 test.c`
 I am greeted with:

```
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:356:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:359:27: fatal error: bits/wordsize.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Now, browsing those files, it seems as if they are in the wrong folder because. I'm not sure what to do here.

Contents of `/usr/include/features.h:586`

```
#  include <x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h>
```

Which gives an error on line 359. That line is shown here:

```
#include <bits/wordsize.h>
```

The file is ACTUALLY located here:
`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h`

Comment: Just guessing here, but make sure you have something like [gcc multilib](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gcc-4.4-multilib) installed, so you really have 32-bit libraries and such.

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll re-install it to make sure :)

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC should support or run with `multilib` to eliminate this error.